# How do I use an if statement using object property, then replace the object property?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a series of if statements based on the object "pest"'s property of "state" and then replace it with a new state. How can I do this?

```
<body>

<img style="vertical-align:middle" id="pet" src="https://i.imgsafe.org/f726448be6.png">
<table>
<tr>
  <th><button id="feed" onclick="buttonFeed"> Feed </button></th>
  <th><button id="10pm" onclick="buttonLate"> 10pm </button></th>
  <th><button id="play" onclick="buttonPlay"> Play </button></th>
  <th><button id="pet" onclick="buttonPet"> Pet </button></th>
  <th><button id="cuddle" onclick="buttonCuddle"> Cuddle </button></th>
</tr>
</table>
```

```
var pest = {
    type:"dog",
    state:"Happy"}

function buttonFeed() {
  if (pest.state === "Happy" || "Relaxed") {
    pest.state = "Sleepy"
    document.getElementById("pet").src="https://i.imgsafe.org/f726267ded.png"
  } else if (pest.state === "Hungry" || "Michevous") {
    pest.state = "Happy"
    document.getElementById("pet").src="https://i.imgsafe.org/f726448be6.png"
  } else if (pest.state === "Sleepy") {
    pest.state = "Relaxed"
    document.getElementById("pet").src="https://i.imgsafe.org/f72630373c.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `pest.state === "Happy" || pest.state === "Relaxed"` (and same for the second condition), otherwise this will work.

Comment: What does your code do now? Did you try walking through the code in your debugger to watch exactly what it does?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. I would also use === just in case as that makes sure that the type is the same...i.e. you are comparing a string to a string. You would want to also do pest.state, instead of pest ["state"].

Just so the answer is actual within the selected answer:

When creating an object in JS it should be done in the following way:

```
var pest = {state: "Happy", type: "dog"};
```

To access attributes in the object do the following:

```
pest.state; pest.type;
```

When checking multiple values in an if statement use the following:

```
if (pest.state === "Happy" || pest.state === "Relaxed")
```

Function calls made in html referencing Javascript also need parentheses:

```
Onclick="buttonFeed()"
```

Comment: Yes, assuming object is defined somewhere within that function or as a parameter for the function.

Comment: Meant to say that pest is defined, not object*

Comment: I lied. If your object looks like this: pest = { state: "Happy"} then in order to get the actual value of the state attribute in pest you would want to do pest.state, not pest ["state"]

Comment: var pest = {
  type:"dog", 
  state:"Happy"}

Comment: For some reason the button functions are not working, any ideas?

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you ever used dev tools on any of the browsers? Personally I like Google Chromes the best. If you go into Google Chrome and press F12, in the console are there any errors?

Comment: In the onClick methods, you need to add parentheses so for example, you need buttonFeed(), instead of buttonFeed

Comment: I checked the console and nothing came up, so I don't think there are any errors

Comment: I think that was it!!

Comment: No I didn't, but in the comments I mentioned that. I will edit my answer. When I originally answered this info was missing and he didn't have the html.